# Flash/AS3 Framerate in tile-based game is low, despite all tiles being converted to a single bitmap

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I'm working on a small game in Flash (AS3) that generates levels using small tiles.

The location,width,height and other properties of the tile are stored in an array upon generation. Each tile is added to the same container movieclip. When all tiles have been generated, the container movieclip is converted to a bitmap, all tiles are removed from the stage, and the original container is removed from the stage and then deleted. The bitmap is the only remaining "graphic" on the stage, aside from the player.

This yields far better performance than allowing all 60,000+ tiles to be rendered individually during gameplay; however, the framerate still reduces as the number of tiles is increased. This makes no sense, as all the tiles are added to a single bitmap that is always the same size, regardless of the amount of tiles.

With 20,000 tiles during generation, the game runs at the full FPS, but with 60,000 it runs relatively choppy, probably around 4-5 FPS.

I've removed collision detection and any/every script that runs through the tile array to rule out the possibility that some other CPU intensive part of the script is lagging the framerate.

Any idea why, despite the fact that all tiles have been removed from the stage and their container is deleted, the game is still running slow even though the background bitmap contains the same amount of data regardless of the number of tiles generated?

Here is the last part of the level generation algorithm which converts the container movieclip to a bitmap and then removes all the tiles:

```
        var temp_bitmap_data:BitmapData = new BitmapData(this.stage_background_mc.width,this.stage_background_mc.height);

        temp_bitmap_data.draw(this.stage_background_mc);

        this.stage_background_bitmap = new Bitmap(temp_bitmap_data);


        main_class.main.stage.addChild(this.stage_background_bitmap);

        for (var block in blocks_array)
        {

             //every block in blocks_array has a child that is the actual graphic of the tile
             blocks_array[block]["block"].removeChild(blocks_array[block]["block"].getChildAt(0));

            if (blocks_array[block]["type"] == "bg_block")
            {
                this.stage_background_mc.removeChild(blocks_array[block]["block"]);
                blocks_array[block]["block"] = null;
            }
            if (blocks_array[block]["type"] == "path_block")
            {

                //path_blocks have a second child in addition to the first one that's already been removed. the second child is the only other child
                blocks_array[block]["block"].removeChild(blocks_array[block]["block"].getChildAt(0));
                this.stage_background_mc.removeChild(blocks_array[block]["block"]);             

            }




        }

        this.stage_background_mc = null;
```

[Edit]
Here is a picture of the game to give you a better idea of what's going on:
[image: the game level]

### [Update:]

Even removing the final created bitmap from the stage, ending up with only 1 child on stage, and setting that removed bitmap to null  doesn't improve the speed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A couple of thoughts.

First, you're sorta half taking advantage of AS3's quick work with blitting. You've got the right idea about having only one single `Bitmap` on the stage, but the steps before (adding `DisplayObjects` to a `MovieClip` and the doing `draw` on that `MovieClip`) isn't the fastest process. For one thing, `BitmapData.draw` is slower than `BitmapData.copyPixels` ([here](http://jacksondunstan.com/articles/1417) is a post on that). One of the best ways to get speed is to pre-blit all of your graphics, and store them as `BitmapData`. Then, keep `Object` references (containing position, etc) for each graphic. In your render loop, run through each object, and use `copyPixels` to copy the graphic's pixel information to the appropriate positon in your single, on-stage Bitmap. This way, all slow `BitmapData.draw` commands have happened upfront, and now you are just pushing pixels, which Flash is really fast at.

That process isn't without its downsides, however. For instance, you can't do easy transforms with it. You'd have to pre-blit all frames of a rotation, for instance, in order to rotate the individual graphic (since you can't rotate a BitmapData, and you aren't using `draw` on a `DisplayObject`). Still, it is mighty fast if you can live with the limitations.

Here is a [post](http://www.8bitrocket.com/2007/12/23/flash-as3-speed-tests-rendering-and-update-models/) that serves as a tutorial of the process I explained above. It is old, but informative none-the-less.

Finally, 60,000 is a very large number. Flash isn't exactly a "speed demon." No matter how optimized, eventually you'll hit a limit. Just something to keep in mind.

Oh, and this additional [post](http://jacksondunstan.com/articles/1675) gives some great tips on performance in Flash.

Comment: Great answer, I will definitely switch over my generation method to use this technique, I knew I was doing something wrong. Hopefully this fixes it. Now, in reference to your comment on 60,000 being a very large number: this is very true; however, yesterday I ran a loop that generates thousands of tiles per frame, and immediately removes them from the stage but continues to hold onto all of their properties. I ran it until it hit over 600,000 tiles while maintaining 24fps before deciding that I will never run into an impractical limit for the scale of my game.

Comment: so the limitation lies somewhere in the way Flash is handling the actual graphics (the way that I've done it), because I was storing 600,000 tiles' properties without a hitch. I will come back to this question and post whether or not this solves my problem when I get it implemented.

Comment: I suspect that your suggestions will solve my problem, as there will only ever actually be 3 movieclips, and the movieclips seem to be what are causing the problem. Thanks a lot! I am going to hold out on giving you the answer until I get to test it.